# Disable server query during build

Tags: next.js, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo, graphql-js

We have a docker image that sets up the backend server and the frontend NextJS application that is using ApolloClient. During the build process of the NextJS application the Apollo client tries to query the backend server'd graphql endpoint which is not working because the server has not been started.

Is there any way to have the ApolloClient NOT query outside servers during build time?
Here's the constructor:

```js
function createApolloClient() {
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
    link: createUploadLink({
      uri: process.env.HOSTNAME + '/graphql',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache({
      typePolicies: {
        Query: {
          fields: {
            allPosts: concatPagination(),
          },
        },
      },
    }),
    onError: ({ networkError, graphQLErrors }) => {
      console.log('graphQLErrors', graphQLErrors)
      console.log('networkError', networkError)
    }
  })
}
```

Ultimately what we want to have is one docker container running the backend (Java) server that serves the NextJS built static files.

Comment: How can the Next.js app be built if it can't query the backend API?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear from your question, but when do you *want* your query to be run?

- If it's supposed to be build time, why is the backend server not running? Where is Next.js supposed to get the data from then?
- At request time, by the server? Use [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#server-side-rendering)
- At request time, by the client (browser?) Check for `typeof(window) !== 'undefined'` and use fetch + async/await.

Comment: I want the query(ies) to run when users interact with the app that would require querying the backend API, so probably option 3 that you listed. Thanks for the pointer, I'll look into it!

Comment: Then yeah, those fetches would bypass next.js altogether and query your API directly from the clientside using standard ES6: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch